# creating rest client in c++ codeblocks?

Tags: c++, web-services, c++11, codeblocks

I am trying to create a rest-api client in c++ in codeblocks compiler . That is why , I am [following this tutorial :](https://mariusbancila.ro/blog/2013/08/19/full-fledged-client-server-example-with-cpprest-sdk-110/)

```
#include <cpprest/http_listener.h>
#include <cpprest/json.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "cpprest110_1_1")

using namespace web;
using namespace web::http;
using namespace web::http::experimental::listener;

#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#define TRACE(msg)            wcout << msg
#define TRACE_ACTION(a, k, v) wcout << a << L" (" << k << L", " << v << L")\n"

map<utility::string_t, utility::string_t> dictionary;

/* handlers implementation */

int main()
{
   http_listener listener(L"http://localhost/restdemo");

   listener.support(methods::GET, handle_get);
   listener.support(methods::POST, handle_post);
   listener.support(methods::PUT, handle_put);
   listener.support(methods::DEL, handle_del);

   try
   {
      listener
         .open()
         .then([&listener](){TRACE(L"\nstarting to listen\n");})
         .wait();

      while (true);
   }
   catch (exception const & e)
   {
      wcout << e.what() << endl;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Now when I am going to rub the cpp file in codeblocks , then I am getting the following error :

**`fatal error: cpprest/http_listener.h: No such file or directory`**

How can I solve this error ? Can you please give me any link from where I can the idea to create rest-api and rest-client in c++ in codeblocks ?

Comment: The error feels quite self-explanatory: compiler couldn't find file `http_listener.h` in folder `cpprest` in any of known include locations. Where is your file located?

Comment: I do not know how to link external header file with my project in codeblocks .

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the path to your include files. E.g. the path to http_listener.h is

```
/a/b/cpprest/http_listener.h
```

In codeblocks open Project -> Build options... -> Search directories. In tabCompiler add

```
/a/b
```

Now the compiler will find your includes. Next you have to set the linker search paths in tab Linker if you get `undefined reference`.